# jQuery Ajax PHP - Upload audio / video files

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, audio, video

**Issue** - upload audio / video files using jquery ajax with php. The same script able to upload image file, but fails for audio / video files.

**Environment** - WAMP server, audio file size - 8 MB, video - 25 MB.

**Script**

1. jQuery AJAX code.

   ```
   jq.ajax ({
           type: "post",
           url: "test.php",
           data: new FormData(jq("#form")[0]),                
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           async: false,
           beforeSend: function() {
               jq(".msg").html("<img src='wait.gif'>");
           },
           success: function(response) {
               jq(".msg").html(response);
           },
           complete: function() {
               jq("#form")[0].reset();
           },
       });
   ```
2. PHP code (test.php).

   print_r($_REQUEST);

In this file form values are not showing while uploading audio (mp3 etc) / video (wmv etc) files.

**Questions** - Please let me know what can cause the issue. Please rectify, suggest and help me resolve the issue.

Comment: please do check your php.ini update file size limit, in default i think is only 8MB, then you should set it higher since you need upload bigger file size like video type.

Comment: This is 64M in php.ini file.

Comment: if post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in php.ini file was set properly, then need to check on your test.php contain any error or not.

Comment: post_max_size was not updated. It has been updated now. Its working. Thank you Deeper.

Comment: Please provide your working code with post_max_size as an Answer so that future visitors can learn from it as well.

Comment: Could you provide the test.php code?

Answer (score 1):

Update the limits(according to how big file you want uploading to support) in your php.ini file for:

post_max_size, upload_max_size